# if $L:V\to V'$ is a surjective linear aplication, and $W$ is a subspace of $v$, exists isomorphism $\frac{V}{W+\ker{L}}$ and $\frac{V'}{L(W)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $L\colon V\to V'$ a surjective linear map. Let $W\subseteq V$ a vector subspace. I'm trying to show that exists an isomorphism
$$ \frac{V}{W+\ker{L}}\simeq \frac{V'}{L(W)}. $$

I think to define the map $T'\colon V\to V'/L(W)$ such that $T'(a)=L(a)+L(W)$. But I cannot continue.

P.D. Sorry for my english

Comment: You just need to show your $T'$ is linear, surjective, and has kernel $W+\ker L$.  Which of these do you have difficulty with?

Comment: @EricWofsey i have difficults proving that $\ker T'=W+\ker L$

Comment: Hint: $\ker T'=L^{-1}[L[W]]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align}
v \in \ker T'
& \iff L(v)+L(W) = L(W) \\
& \iff L(v) \in L(W) \\
& \iff (\exists w \in W) \ L(v)=L(w) \\
& \iff (\exists w \in W) \ v-w \in \ker L \\
& \iff v \in W + \ker L.
\end{align}